# Other than network what can affect ping times?

Tags: ping, aix

I have a database server running on a AIX box.  When pinging the server I see increased ping times at certain times.  I am directly connected to the box and usually see 0ms or 1ms ping times.  Sometimes I see ping times of 10ms to 12ms.  I am wondering a bit how ping is actually implemented in the TCP stack.  If the number of other open connections could affect its responsiveness.  Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We have found that processor preemption is causing problems with ping latency.  (Where PHYP steals the whole processor over to itself or to another LPAR.)  If you can, try switching to dedicated processors.  There are more subtle ways to get good results but I'm the network guy, not the CPU perf guy so I'm sorta out of my league.

In 6.1 TL06 SP05 until about 6.1 TL07 SP05, processor folding was also broken.  The work around was to set vpm_cpu_folding (I think thats the name of it) to 4.  The same is true for 7.1 releases that came out at the same time.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I have two network interfaces... one always seems to show ping times of 0ms but the other (with about 5000 active connections) shows ping times ***sometimes*** around 10 to 12ms.  I suspect that there is a "ping" process and ping is not part of the network stack itself, so it is being affected by the number of connections.

Comment: Its more likely that your ping packet is backed up on the transmit queue.  There is no ping process and ping is part of the network stack